# what is the way to show previous or next video using React State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using Map method to with function to Set State to Change url of video. So whenever i click on any video from list it change the state hence my videos are change in Player .

The problem is that i want to have two button next and Previous to Show previous & next  video, i dont have any idea how to do that Here is My Code

```js
// import React from "react";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

const List = [
  {
    title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
    innerList: [
      {
        innertitle: "1 Two imprisoned",
        describe:"1 Client has methods for creating new data and offers a type-safe way to do it. In this lesson, we take a look at how to add new records in our database by hitting an API routeRehan1",
        url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/netdesignr-ltd/video/upload/v1662112952/How%20to%20smart%20money%20concepts/videoplayback_2_uoihtg.mp4",
        poster:
          "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_.jpg",
        time: "2m",
      },
      {
        innertitle: "2 Two imprisoned",
        describe:"2 Client has methods for creating new data and offers a type-safe way to do it. In this lesson, we take a look at how to add new records in our database by hitting an API routeRehan1",

        url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/netdesignr-ltd/video/upload/v1662099142/How%20to%20smart%20money%20concepts/videoplayback_dvjulu.mp4",
        poster:
          "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_.jpg",
        time: "2h 22m",
      },
      {
        innertitle: "3 Two imprisoned",
        describe:"3 Client has methods for creating new data and offers a type-safe way to do it. In this lesson, we take a look at how to add new records in our database by hitting an API routeRehan1",
        url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/netdesignr-ltd/video/upload/v1662112893/How%20to%20smart%20money%20concepts/videoplayback_aw5zoh.mp4",
        poster:
          "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_.jpg",
        time: "2h 22m",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
    innerList: [
      {
        innertitle: "1 Two imprisoned",
        describe:"1 Client has methods for creating new data and offers a type-safe way to do it. In this lesson, we take a look at how to add new records in our database by hitting an API routeRehan1",
        url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/netdesignr-ltd/video/upload/v1662112952/How%20to%20smart%20money%20concepts/videoplayback_2_uoihtg.mp4",
        poster:
          "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_.jpg",
        time: "2h 22m",
      },
      {
        innertitle: "2 Two imprisoned",
        describe:"2 Client has methods for creating new data and offers a type-safe way to do it. In this lesson, we take a look at how to add new records in our database by hitting an API routeRehan1",

        url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/netdesignr-ltd/video/upload/v1662099142/How%20to%20smart%20money%20concepts/videoplayback_dvjulu.mp4",
        poster:
          "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_.jpg",
        time: "2h 22m",
      },
      {
        innertitle: "3 Two imprisoned",
        describe:"3 Client has methods for creating new data and offers a type-safe way to do it. In this lesson, we take a look at how to add new records in our database by hitting an API routeRehan1",
        url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/netdesignr-ltd/video/upload/v1662112893/How%20to%20smart%20money%20concepts/videoplayback_aw5zoh.mp4",
        poster:
          "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_.jpg",
        time: "2h 22m",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
    innerList: [
      {
        innertitle: "1 Two imprisoned",
        describe:"1 Client has methods for creating new data and offers a type-safe way to do it. In this lesson, we take a look at how to add new records in our database by hitting an API routeRehan1",
        url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/netdesignr-ltd/video/upload/v1662112952/How%20to%20smart%20money%20concepts/videoplayback_2_uoihtg.mp4",
        poster:
          "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_.jpg",
        time: "2h 22m",
      },
      {
        innertitle: "2 Two imprisoned",
        describe:"2 Client has methods for creating new data and offers a type-safe way to do it. In this lesson, we take a look at how to add new records in our database by hitting an API routeRehan1",

        url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/netdesignr-ltd/video/upload/v1662099142/How%20to%20smart%20money%20concepts/videoplayback_dvjulu.mp4",
        poster:
          "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_.jpg",
        time: "2h 22m",
      },
      {
        innertitle: "3 Two imprisoned",
        describe:"3 Client has methods for creating new data and offers a type-safe way to do it. In this lesson, we take a look at how to add new records in our database by hitting an API routeRehan1",
        url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/netdesignr-ltd/video/upload/v1662112893/How%20to%20smart%20money%20concepts/videoplayback_aw5zoh.mp4",
        poster:
          "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_.jpg",
        time: "2h 22m",
      },
    ],
  },
];
// when click on previous button show previous video 
export function WatchList() {



    const [previos, setPrevios] = useState(false);

  const [list, setList] = React.useState({
    title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
    innerTitle: "Two imprisoned",
    describe:"Client has methods for creating new data and offers a type-safe way to do it. In this lesson, we take a look at how to add new records in our database by hitting an API routeRehan1",
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hB3S9bIaco",
    time: "2h 22m",
  });
  


  const handleVideoData = (data: any,index:any) => {
    setList(data);
   
  };

  const previousVideo = () => {


  

  }


  

  return (
    <div className="mx-auto w-full bg-smart-60 p-2">
      <div className="mx-auto flex flex-col md:flex-row">
        <div className="p-8 md:grid-cols-3">
          <div className="h-96  w-full overflow-auto  bg-smart-50 px-4 md:h-screen md:w-[320px]  ">
            <div>
              <div className="mt-5 flex justify-center">
                <img src="/logo.webp" alt="logo" width={200} height={200} />
              </div>
              <div className="-m-4 mb-4 border-b border-blue-900 px-4 py-6"></div>
            </div>
            {List.map((data, i) => (
              <div className="mb-6" key={i}>
                <div className="p-2">
                  <p className="font-semibold tracking-wider text-smart-70">
                    {data.title}
                  </p>
                </div>
                {data.innerList.map((data, i) => (
                  <ul key={i}>
                    <button
                      className="w-full"
                      onClick={() => {
                        handleVideoData(data,i);
                      }}
                    >
                      <li className="group mb-2 rounded-lg border border-transparent bg-gradient-to-br from-transparent to-transparent px-2 py-3 transition duration-200 ease-in-out hover:from-blue-500 hover:to-blue-900">
                        <div className="flex">
                          <img
                            className="m-auto mr-4 w-24 rounded-md"
                            src="/thumbnail.webp"
                            alt="imageslist"
                          />
                          <div className="w-full text-left">
                            <div className="">
                              <p className="mr-2 text-smart-70">
                                {data.innertitle}
                              </p>
                            </div>
                            <p className="inline-block text-sm text-gray-500 group-hover:text-gray-300">
                              {data.time}
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </button>
                  </ul>
                ))}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="grid md:grid-cols-9 ">
          <div className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-9">
            <section className="sticky top-0 mb-6">
              <nav className="bg-mid-deep flex flex-col justify-between rounded-xl bg-opacity-30 px-6 py-4 text-gray-200 md:flex-row">
                <section className="my-auto">
                  <h1>
                    <span className="font-semibold text-gray-200">
                    {list.title}
                    </span>
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                      fill="currentColor"
                      aria-hidden="true"
                      className="inline-block w-5"
                    >
                      <path
                        fillRule="evenodd"
                        d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z"
                        clipRule="evenodd"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                    <span className="text-gray-400">
                       {list.innerTitle}
                    </span>
                  </h1>
                </section>
                <section className="mt-2 flex w-full md:mt-0 md:justify-end xl:w-1/3">
                  <button className="mr-2 flex flex-row rounded-xl border border-blue-900 px-4 py-2 text-left text-xs text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-300 sm:text-sm">
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                      fill="currentColor"
                      aria-hidden="true"
                      className="my-auto mr-2 inline-block w-4"
                    >
                      <path d="M9 2a1 1 0 000 2h2a1 1 0 100-2H9z"></path>
                      <path
                        fillRule="evenodd"
                        d="M4 5a2 2 0 012-2 3 3 0 003 3h2a3 3 0 003-3 2 2 0 012 2v11a2 2 0 01-2 2H6a2 2 0 01-2-2V5zm3 4a1 1 0 000 2h.01a1 1 0 100-2H7zm3 0a1 1 0 000 2h3a1 1 0 100-2h-3zm-3 4a1 1 0 100 2h.01a1 1 0 100-2H7zm3 0a1 1 0 100 2h3a1 1 0 100-2h-3z"
                        clipRule="evenodd"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                    <span className="my-auto">Show Transcripts</span>
                  </button>
                  <button className="flex rounded-xl border border-blue-900 px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-300">
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      fill="none"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      aria-hidden="true"
                      className="my-auto mr-2 inline-block w-4"
                    >
                      <path
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round"
                        d="M17 16l4-4m0 0l-4-4m4 4H7m6 4v1a3 3 0 01-3 3H6a3 3 0 01-3-3V7a3 3 0 013-3h4a3 3 0 013 3v1"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                    <span className="my-auto">Log in</span>
                  </button>
                </section>
              </nav>
            </section>
            <div className="sticky top-20 grid grid-cols-9 gap-6">
              <section className="col-span-9">
                <div className="sticky top-20">
                  <section className="w-full rounded-xl">
                    <section className="flex">
                      <ReactPlayer
                        url={list.url}
                        controls={true}
                        width="100%"
                        height="600px"
                      />
                    </section>
                    <section className="flex justify-between bg-smart-50 px-4 py-8">
                      <div className="rounded-md ">
                        <p className="text-xl text-white sm:text-3xl">
                        {list.innerTitle}
                        </p>
                        <p className="mt-1 text-gray-500">{list.time}</p>
                        <div className="mt-4">
                          <p className="text-sm text-gray-400 sm:text-lg">
                          {list.describe}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="my-auto flex ">
                        <button>
                          <svg
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            fill="none"
                            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            strokeWidth="2"
                            stroke="currentColor"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            className="mr-2 inline-block w-8 cursor-pointer text-gray-400 hover:text-red-400"
                          >
                            <path
                              strokeLinecap="round"
                              strokeLinejoin="round"
                              d="M4.318 6.318a4.5 4.5 0 000 6.364L12 20.364l7.682-7.682a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364-6.364L12 7.636l-1.318-1.318a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364 0z"
                            ></path>
                          </svg>
                        </button>
                        <span className="my-auto text-sm text-gray-400">0</span>
                      </div>
                    </section>
                  </section>
                  <section className="mt-4 rounded-md bg-smart-50">
                    <section className="bg-mid-deep flex justify-between rounded-xl bg-opacity-30 px-6 py-4">


                      <button onClick={() => previousVideo()} className="rounded-xl border border-blue-500 px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-300">
                        ← Previous
                      </button>
                      <button  className="rounded-xl border border-blue-500 px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-200 hover:text-blue-300">
                        Next →
                      </button>
                    </section>
                  </section>
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Current Looking of Page]

Comment: Can you share the css file? I am trying to reproduce your work.

Comment: its all in  tailwind

Answer (score 0):

I think this task can be accomplished using a simple index:

```
 const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

 const previousVideo = () => {
    const newIndex = index > 0 ? index - 1 : 0;
    setIndex(newIndex);
    setList(List[index]);
  };
```

Of course, you will have to adapt the data from `List` to the one in `list`, but that should be easy.